# Translate month in 'Get date'

Tags: magento-1.7, date

I have a news page in my magento store which is displaying news posts with a publish date, my store is built in 2 languages, the code which is creating the format:

```
public function getPublishDate($format = 'd F Y')
    {
        return $this->getDateCreatedFormated($format);
    }
```

This is the code in my Code\Model folder.

The problem is in, both languages the month is shown in English, how can i make sure the English pays shows the English date, and my other language, shows, ofcourse, the other languaeg.

Comment: It will help if you post the code in the method getDateCreatedFormated you are using

Answer (score 2):

Not having seen the code that you have, which formats your date, I am not sure if you are already using the correct formatting 'the magento way'

However, in case not, try this, and see if it works: (note, have not tested this)

See `Mage_Core_Helper_Data::format()`, which claims it will format the date according to the locale settings.

```
/**
 * Format date using current locale options
 *
 * @param   date|Zend_Date|null $date in GMT timezone
 * @param   string $format (full, long, medium, short)
 * @param   bool $showTime
 * @return  string
 */
public function formatDate($date=null, $format='short', $showTime=false)
{
....
}
```

so a call like this will potentially result in the correct 'locale specific' result:

```
Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($dateToFormat, 'medium', false);
```

Hope that helps.